# "Прежде всего" как вводное и как член предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Как отличить, "прежде всего" является вводным или является членом предложения. Например: *Прежде всего, их необходимо ценить, уважать и беззаветно любить...* Здесь же, если не ошибаюсь, "прежде всего" то же, что "главное", тогда это вводное. Или все-таки "прежде всего" здесь как "в первую очередь", следовательно, член предложения?

Comment: _**Стася: Как отличить, "прежде всего" является вводным или является членом предложения**_. === Отличить можно, лишь зная контекст и интонацию. Попутно замечу, что и "в первую очередь" в этой позиции могло бы быть обособлено. /// 

Скорее всего, запятая в вашем предложении будет нужна. А может и нет -- ведь автор мог делать акцент не на последних словах приведённой Вами части  предложения, а, к примеру, на местоимении "их": _Прежде всего ИХ необходимо ценить, уважать и беззаветно любить…_ (а не кого-то там ещё).

Comment: slava1947, у меня рука не поднимается поставить тут запятую. Просто думаю, а вдруг ошибаюсь. Розенталя, Лопатина перечитала, яснее не стало.  А если акцент на "ценить, уважать. любить", то нужна запятая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Все зависит от контекста, от структуры предложения, от авторской позиции**.

Вариант1. Они многое пережили в своей жизни, прежде всего их необходимо ценить, уважать и беззаветно любить.

Вариант 2. **Прежде всего **, (пауза!) их необходимо ценить, уважать и беззаветно любить.  Всё остальное тоже важно, но не в такой степени.

Значение вводного слов: "во первых, главное", причем речь идет **о перечислении, о разных сторонах вопроса.**

**Еще парный вариант**: (1) **Прежде всего**, это свидетельство того, что реклама включилась в бизнес-процесс и нашла в нём своё место. Во-вторых, это... (2) **Прежде всего** это свидетельство того, что реклама включилась в бизнес-процесс и нашла в нём своё место (просто вывод, продолжения нет, разные стороны не рассматриваются).

2) Но иногда синтаксическая роль вводного слова определяется по структуре предложения однозначно, например: Прежде всего, этот проклятый Вар-равван вас не тревожит? [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 2 (1929-1940)]

Прежде всего ему нужна мать! Нормальная, сидящая дома мать! [Екатерина Орлова. Такой же хороший, как ты // «Даша», 2004]

Прежде всего я хочу сказать, что горжусь тем, что стал маленькой частью этого необыкновенного наследия. [Джим Кэрри -- изнутри и снаружи (2004) // «Экран и сцена», 2004.05.06]

Answer (score 0):

Если "прежде всего" означает "во-первых", то вводное. Если оно означает "в первую очередь", "сначала", то не вводное.

Comment: Спасибо, это я знаю. А в этом конкретном предложении, что оно обозначает?

Comment: Я бы обособил. Но @slava1947 указал, в каком случае не обособляется. Правда, это слишком уж экзотический вариант.

Comment: "Экзотический" вариант возможен в случае, если вместо многоточия следует противопоставление того, что "не прежде всего", например: ... "а потом уже денег им давать" :)